# Show JSON data on Twig

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

Hello I have the next trouble. I receive a data on JSON format from a WebService and I need read that and show on a twig template.

I receive the object 'cookies'

```
$cream = json_decode($cookies);
```

Now on the object $cream there is another object JSON format with name '$ingredients'

```
$ingredients = json_decode($cream->ingredients);
```

Here is where begin the troubles, I cant manage this object JSON format on twig like I use the Propel Object. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue had with me . i have done this with javascript , so i suggest you too use javascript

```
  {% autoescape false %}   
   var json = {{fit_priority}};
    if(json!=null)  {       
     length_obj=json.length;
     Object.size = function(obj) {
      var size = 0, key;
     for (key in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
       }
       return size;  };  
     var size = Object.size(json);  s="";  s+='<label>Fit Pirority:</label>';  for(var key in json) {
      var count=1;
       s+= '<label>'+key+'</label>';
     s+=' <input type="text" class="required" id="fit_pirority'+count+'"  name="fit_pirority['+key+']"
     value="'+json[key]+'">';     count++; }
       document.getElementById("fit_priority").innerHTML=s; 
     {% endautoescape %}
```